# How to overlap an image over an element inside a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to create a tutorial in my Android app and I want to put some baloons over some UI elements. My UI is built on `LinearLayouts`.

How can I put a floating image over the `LinearLayout` at a specific position (i.e. next to textfield with id="@id/email").

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/email"
        style="@style/LoginBarText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3.0dp"
        android:text="Email:" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I know that the only layout that is able to overlap elements is the RelativeLayout but it doesn't work over elements inside other layouts.

Thanks

Comment: Change your LinearLayout to RelativeLayout then it should work.

Comment: I cannot change it because I need the weight attribute to fill the screen with a percentage. The weight doesn't work with RelativeLayouts

Answer (score 4):

you can create a `RelativeLayout` and include your original `LinearLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <include 
            layout="@layout/layout_original" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <include 
            layout="@layout/layout_overlay" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Or if you need to just add an image next to (not on top of) the element try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
    android:src="@drawable/imagename"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/email"
    style="@style/LoginBarText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3.0dp"
    android:text="Email:" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in the Activity call

```
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: I want to draw the image next to an element inside the LinearLayout (that is not composed of only a textView). I would replace the LinearLayouts with RelativeLayouts but, unfortunately, the weight attribute to assign a width in percentage doesn't work with Relative Layouts

Comment: No because the image must overlap other elements of the layout. I am trying to use also this technique to put a vertical shadow between two fragments layouts but the shadow must overlap the elements on the left side.

Comment: A `RelativeLayout` can contain your `Linearlayout` and all the properties of your `LinearLayout` will remain. So you don't need to recode anything. Then outside the orignal `LinearLayout` tags but inside the `RelativeLaout` tags you would include your overlay elements and specify the position (`android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/email"`) for each element of the overlay.

Comment: I have tried already (I don't think I made a mistake) but it seems that the element is positioned on the left (for example if I specified toLeft) of the LinearLayout container and not of the element inside it. I will try again, but I think this is the behaviour

Comment: yes it is not working, it is not positioned properly. It is like putting no information on the position.